# How to count distinct values in one column for each distinct value in another column in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

Say I have the following data in an Excel sheet:

```
Country Fruit
USA     Banana
USA     Apple
USA     Apple
USA     Orange
USA     Banana
USA     Apple
UK      Banana
UK      Banana
UK      Apple
```

I want to count how many distinct fruits are there for each of the countries. Desired output is as follows:

[image]

What formula can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try the `SUMPRODUCT` formula:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `E23`, fill it down.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((D23:D31 <> "")*(C23:C31=C23:C31),1/COUNTIF(D23:D31,D23:D31 & ""))
  ```

---

**Edit:**

*Adding new formula since @Jeeped inspired me to correct the existing formula to get desire results.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `E23`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((C$23:C$31=C23)/(COUNTIFS(C$23:C$31, C23, D$23:D$31, D$23:D$31)+(C$23:C$31<>C23)))
  ```

**N.B.**

*Since you are suppose to drag formula down therefore to avoid appearing ZEROs after `row 31`, you may use this revised version of the formula.*

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((C$23:C$31=C23)/(COUNTIFS(C$23:C$31, C23, D$23:D$31, D$23:D$31)+(C$23:C$31<>C23)))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT((C$23:C$31=C23)/(COUNTIFS(C$23:C$31, C23, D$23:D$31, D$23:D$31)+(C$23:C$31<>C23))))
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: If you plan to drag that formula down from E23 to E31 you need to lock most of the row numbers (all the ranges) with $ absolute row reference. eg. `D23:D31` needs to be `D$23:D$31`. Without the *$* absolutes, you will get bad results like E27 and E28.

Comment: @Jeeped,, thanks for valuable observation,, if I use SUMPRODUCT((D$23:D$31 <> "") only,, then getting `3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3 & 2`,,, if Absolute reference with `SUMPRODUCT` & `COUNTIF` both then  getting only `3s` .

Comment: You're right of course. E23 should be closer to `=SUMPRODUCT((C$23:C$31=C23)/(COUNTIFS(C$23:C$31, C23, D$23:D$31, D$23:D$31)+(C$23:C$31<>C23)))` then dragged down.

Comment: @Jeeped Okay let me try.

Comment: @Jeeped,, thnaks it's working ☺

Comment: Glad to help you @Kristada673 ,, keep asking ☺